# Escalating custom pick list values...with several variables.

Tags: validation-rule

Our org has a custom pick-list field that shows which round of calling our small call team is currently on for a specific account and contact on a specific calling initiative. We also created a custom field on the Account record named "initiative" and a custom activity field also named "initiative" and the reasoning behind this, is that our company uses calling initiatives to drive business. With these 2 fields, we can quickly find which accounts are on the initiative and can also report on the activities by initiative. All of this was in place when I was handed the Org and I'm still pretty green, so I'm not sure if this is the best use or not.

One of my biggest requests is getting the "code" field to auto escalate, but I have no idea how to write the Validation Rule or whatever code is needed to do this.

Basically, I need the custom activity pick-list named "code" to auto escalate from R1 -> R2 -> R3, etc....when the Account initiative  matches the activity initiative field, as well as the contact matches from the first call to the contact on the second call. Is there anyway to do this? Does this make any sense at all?